# Problems with returning to a previous rendered view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I am having issues with something which might imply I am missing something conceptual.  I am using a view with a controller which populates from a couple of different services(asynchronous).  Everything works fine the FIRST time the view is navigated to.  All the expected elements get populated in the controller and the dom is rendered perfectly.  However,  the SECOND time a user navigates to the same view,  the DOM does not render all the elements.  I have put breaks in the code and have confirmed that the data is populated by the service exactly as it was the first time.

I put a break on a click event so I could inspect the scope post rendering. As expected the first time it is rendered, everything is as expected.  The second time, despite watching the scope variable get set, when I inspect the scope post rendering the variable is undefined!! I have looked to see the $id of the scope.  I can see that the first time the $id of the scope is the same through the whole initialization and rendering.  The second time the controller is initializing the same scope but when I inspect post rendering I can see that the scope has changed and is now different from the one used by the controller to initialize.  I don't understand what created this second scope OR why the first scope was used to initialize the controller.

So my question(s) to the AngularJS folks are as follows:
  1. Are there differences in how Angular behaves from the first and then subsequent route events to the same route.  I have noticed that the pages render faster.
  2. How do $digest/$apply come in to play?  It won't let me call them because I get the inprog error.
  3. How/approaches to debugging this? I really don't understand where to go with this.  Its as if I have lost the two way bindings.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok.  I found the bug.  Its a bug in one of the services I wrote.  It takes a callback and it maintains the list of callbacks but never destroyed them and hence it was calling the prior scopes callback!  However this leads to one more question.  When do scopes get destroyed?  Do I need to explicitly destroy a prior scope?  Do I need to explicitly listen to a $location change and destroy myself?

Comment: I recommend you the Batarang Chrome extension

Comment: I am. Thanks.  I implemented a listener in my service to destroy the "stale" callbacks in its queue.  It is listening to the $on.('destroy') event within the service so consumers don't need to worry about clean up.  All happens automatically. Cool.